# React Hook for a POST call onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I have a button, `onClick` of that button I want to make a `POST` call with some data user has filled in an input field, stored in state, and then redirect the user to another page.

My current code looks like this, but I get an error:

> *React Hook "usePost" is called in function "onAccept" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function*

And the code doesn't work. I have created my own hook for `POST` calls.

What might a way to make the desired functionality work?

What I'm after is the ability to make a POST call and redirect.

Simplified example:

```
// my function
const onAccept = () => {
  const { data, loading, error } = usePost(
    "MY_URL",
    { DATA: MY_DATA }
  );
  if (data && !error) {
    navigate(`/`);
  }
};

// return
<button onClick={() => onAccept()}
```

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You can't use custom hooks within functions. They have to be used in (at the top level) a component or another custom hook.

Comment: Yes I read the error message, but I'm confused what the way to fix it would be? Do I get rid of the custom hook and paste the code from the hook to the onAccept function in order to make a post call?

Comment: Thanks @Andy - does that mean that a "dynamic" use of the usePost through the onClick is not possible to achieve? Seems like a custom hook for making POST calls is not a thing then, as often the call contains data from a form / page otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You are calling `usePost` hook inside of `onAccept` function. You should follow [react hook rule](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

To solve your problem, you can do like that:

your custom hook file:

```
export const usePost = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState()

  const handlePost = useCallback(async (url, data) => {
    // your api request logic in here, bellow only show example
    try {
      const {data, status} = await apiCall(url, data)
      if (data && status === 200) navigate(`/`)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }, [])

  return { handlePost }
  // to return status to component, you can use bellow.
  // return { status, handlePost }
}
```

then your component:

```
const YourComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const { handlePost } = usePost()
  // To get status: const { status, handlePost } = usePost()
  // your other hooks in here
  // Check status
  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === 200) {
      // whatever you want to do
    }
  }, [status])
  
  return (
    <>
      // Your component UI here
      ...
      <button onClick={() => handlePost(url, data)}>
    </>
  )
}
```

You should call your custom hooks(for example: `usePost`) at the top level of component, not nested function body as like as you were doing in your code (`onAccept` function body).

Comment: This one works! Is there a way to return the status of the POST call to the component so that the redirect can happen if the status is 200? I need to keep the redirection (navigate function) within the component, and not in the hook as the hook will be reused with various URL's and bodies.

Comment: @matmik, updated answer to return status to component. With this way, you can share any values you want to use  from api response inside of component. Another way, you can store api response to redux, and use it in any components you need. But I just showed local state solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you do the following.

At first, you should create fetch function which will be returned from `usePost hook`.

example.

```
export const usePost = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  const fetch = () => {
    setStatus(loading)
    apiRequest({
      url: 'my_url',
      method: 'GET',
   
    }).then(response => {
      setStatus(false)
      setData(response.data.data)
    }).catch(e => {
      setStatus(false)
    })
  }

  return {
    status,
    data,
    fetch
  }
```

After all, you can call this hook in your component. It will return `fetch` function. You should call fetch inside `onAccept`.

Example.

```
const { data, loading, fetch } = usePost()

const onAccept = () => {
    fetch()
 }

// return
<button onClick={() => onAccept()}
```

PS. if you need you can return errors from `usePost hook`, as well.

Comment: This example also works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, call you hook from React Function. Read the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions.

Second, you should have some sort of `load` method in your `usePost` hook, e.g.: `const { load } = usePost(...)`, in order to make POST request on click.

So your handler will look like:

```js
const onAccept = () => {
  load();

  // the following block move somewhere before you render the component or better use useEffect hook for that
  // if (data && !error) {
  //   navigate(`/`);
  // }
};
```

I hope this will help.